# nginx : how to specify a /static to point to a docker volume?

Tags: docker, nginx

I have two containers : one front and one back. Both have /static folder to be used. So i ended up pointing these static folders to a common volume staticfiles.

This is my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  
  nginx_cont:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/nginx/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/usr/share/nginx/html/build/static
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - web_cont
    networks:
      spa_network:

  web_cont:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    command: /start
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/app/static
      - mediafiles:/app/media
      - sqlite_db:/app/db  
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./env/prod-sample
    networks:
      spa_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.128.2

networks:
  spa_network:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16

volumes:
  sqlite_db:
  staticfiles:
  mediafiles:
```

My problem is in my nginx: i want to point the /static location to point to this staticfiles volume. How can i do?
At the moment my /static folder is only pointing to one of my container static file and my web app doesnt work. This is my nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost; 
    location / {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html/build;
      index  index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }

    location /wagtail {
        proxy_pass http://172.20.128.2:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /wagtail;
        client_max_body_size 20M;

        }


    location /static/ {
        alias /app/static/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias /app/media/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You *alias* `/static/` to `/app/static/` in your nginx.conf file, so you need to map the volume to `/app/static` like this

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  
  nginx_cont:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/nginx/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/app/static
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - web_cont
    networks:
      spa_network:
```