# nginx alias : how to alias on one proxy server only?

Tags: django, nginx

I'm trying to get working a single page application with django/wagtail and react.

But at the moment I'm serving django content via restframework and the request on media/ and djangostatic/ are not working.

I have configured nginx to serve /media and /djangostatic to alias /app/media and /app/static but this is not working properly.

Here is the nginx.conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost; 
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.20.128.3:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        client_max_body_size 20M;

        }

    location /wagtail {
        proxy_pass http://172.20.128.2:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /wagtail;
        client_max_body_size 20M;

        }

    location /djangostatic/ {
        alias /app/static/;
        }       

    location /media/ {
        alias /app/media/;
    }
}
```

When a page in need of /djangostatic is queried, I get the error :

> 2022/06/12 08:30:10 [error] 22#22: *2 open() "/app/static/wagtailadmin/js/vendor/jquery.datetimepicker.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.20.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /djangostatic/wagtailadmin/js/vendor/jquery.datetimepicker.js?v=021047c1 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/wagtail/cms-admin/login/?next=/wagtail/cms-admin/"

So the alias seems to work (it is replaced by /app/media) but it doesn't open the file. I have checked the backend server container and the file exists.

So my question is simple : the /app/static and /media folders are on  http://172.20.128.2:8000, which is the reverse proxy of /wagtail location. How to make the alias working on the /wagtail location proxy server but not on others?

I could make two servers with different names but I want this to work on the same server with reverse proxy serving the backend and frontend.

Comment: The request was for a static file not a media file. Nginx expects the static files to be in the `/app/static/` directory so you should run `collectstatic` and make sure that all the static files are collected to `/app/static/` on the Nginx server

Comment: Don't use `alias` if the files are on a different server. Use `proxy_pass`.

Comment: You should share the `/app/static` and `/app/media` folders with the nginx container using some kind of a shared volume.

Comment: @IvanShatsky well i have an unanswered question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72536548/nginx-how-to-specify-a-static-to-point-to-a-docker-volume on how to point to a docker volume, which can be configured as a shared volume

Comment: @RichardSmith I have tried proxy_pass but the static files are not served even if i dont have an error on the get request...this is because django doesnt serve static and media files and let this issue to the server configuration